# php code to assign different value from textbox to each no inside forloop

Tags: php, pdo

I am generating Number using for loop.

My number pattern is like below table.

1
2
3
4
5
6

ok now I need to **assign every no has price which i getting it from textbox.**

For Ex - My input value in **pricetextbox = 10,20,30,40,50,60 in comma exploded form.**

**Now I need is get textbox array data inside forloop and assign every No has textbox value and generate like below data**

1    - 10

2    - 20

3    -30

4     -40

5    -50

6    -60     etc..

plz tell me how can do this or this is possible.

below is my forllop code

```
for($row2=1;$row2<=6;$row2++)
        {

         }
```

Comment: i only need if user enter 10,20,30,40,50,60 in one textbox then for loop get every  textbox no and assign to the for loop no....for ex--  my for loop runs 1 to 6 times then it gets every time new value from textbox...for ex -- 1-10,2-20,-3-30 like so....

Comment: my clear que is how to pass comma exploded value from textbox inside for loop

Comment: `foreach(explode(',', '10,20,30,40,50,60') as $k=>$v)`

Comment: how to get this from textbox inside this for($row2=1;$row2<=6;$row2++)
        {
$pricetextbox = $_POST['c1_price'];
         }

Comment: bcoz user enter entering value inside textbox.

Comment: You want 6 separate text boxes with a number (10, 20, 30.. etc) written inside them?

Comment: ok then how to pass 6 txtbox data inside loop..  plz show me the piece of code i can not understand how to pass textbox data inside loop...

Comment: i try below code with one txtbox this working.. but getting only laste value of textbox in each row.   $c1_price = $_POST['c1_price'];                   
for($row2=1;$row2<=6;$row2++)
        {          foreach(explode(',',$c1_price) as $k=>$v)
          {
           $c1price = $v; 
          } }

Answer (score 0):

This code used to generate unique No in each iterations for for loop.

If you need this value dynamic then change loop count with textbox name.

for ex-

```
 $loopCount = 0;
    for($row2=1;$row2<=6;$row2++)
            {

    $Pric = $loopCount++ + 1;

}
```